# I'm unable to make a POST request to a backend endpoint created with Django REST framework

Tags: forms, post, request, fetch, endpoint

**In the code below I'm trying to make a POST request to that endpoint url and it keeps giving me error code of 400.
**

Here's a link to the endpoint: https://houserentmanagementsystem-production.up.railway.app/api/user/register

Here's my code:::

const sendRequest =  async  (text) => {

```
    setIsLoading(true);

    setError(null);

    try{

const response = await fetch('https://houserentmanagementsystem-production.up.railway.app/api/user/register', {

        method: 'POST',

        body: JSON.stringify(text),

        headers:{

            'Content-Type': 'application/json',

            'Accept': 'application/json'

        }

    })

    if(!response.ok) {

        throw new Error('Request Failed')

        

    }

    const data = await response.json();

    console.log(data);

    

} catch (err) {

    console.log(err)

    setError(err.message || 'Something went wrong')

    console.log(text)

}

setIsLoading(false);

}



 const submitHandler = (event) => {
```

event.preventDefault();

const userDetails = {

```
first_name: isFirstname,

last_name: isLastname,

email: enterdEmail,

username: enteredUsername,

phone_number: enteredPhone,

password: enteredPassword,

confirm_password: enteredConfirmedPass,

signuptype: signupType.current.value
```

}

```
sendRequest(userDetails);

console.log('this is sent', userDetails)

}
```